# PHP to htaccess?

Tags: php, .htaccess, cookies, http-headers

```
<?php
    setcookie('a', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    header(location: "index2.php");
?>
```

im new to .htaccess and wonder how to convert this php script to .htaccess code

here are lines what I tried with .htaccess, but din't work:

```
Header set Set-Cookie a=REQUEST_URI
Header set Set-Cookie "a=REQUEST_URI; path=/;"
Header set Set-Cookie "language=%{REQUEST_URI}e; path=/;"
```

is there any way of doing this in mod_rewrite?

:)

Comment: Just a hunch - do you or does your provider allow header in .htaccess files? Just recently, I spent few furious hours over a php_flag in my .htaccess :)

Comment: header in .htaccess files are now allowed but cookie value is "null"
but it should be file location

Comment: Have you tried wrapping it in quotes? Eg. http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/htaccess-fresh.html#modrewrite4

Comment: Any particular reason for doing such a thing?

Comment: so that index2.php would get requested file name for jquery loader

Answer (score 1):

Because you mentioned mod_rewrite, I was able to use the following mod_rewrite .htaccess code to produce the effect you want:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.+)/?$ index2.php [CO=testcookie:%{REQUEST_URI}:localhost,R,L]
```

I get a cookie set with the current URI and a redirect to index2.php as expected.

`CO` sets a cookie (name:value:domain), `R` is redirect, `L` means "last rule". Of course, you'll have to change cookie domain, path and lifetime information as appropriate. More information [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html).

Is this what you were trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

I am gaining experience in using .htaccess files as well but from what I've see in a few other's work, you may need to keep your code in a script if you're trying to set a specific-duration cookie you will have to keep it in a php script while a session based cookie is possible in the .htaccess file. This link may help with your approach: http://www.webmasterworld.com/apache/3694277.htm

Comment: actually there is only one problem with my .htaccess code, REQUEST_URI doesn't seem to work in mod_headers and thus giving  cookie values: "REQUEST_URI" or "null", if one was to view "any file" on my web cookie "a" value should be "any file"?

Comment: Read into your comments above about needing to get the requested file name for jquery loader and you may want to try using REQUEST_FILENAME and see if it will work properly..if you haven't already

Comment: Like World War One, thought to be blitz but vice versa. I also tried with REQUEST_FILENAME, maybe synthax is not right inserting REQUEST_FILENAME/REQUEST_URI in mod_headers?